# Adding multiple rewrites to config.xml

Tags: xml, url-rewrite, multiple, regex

I'm trying to add a few url rewrites into the config.xml file in the "app/etc/" folder.

I am not using the url rewrite function in magento itself because in need to be able to use regex.

I tried the following:

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <custom_url1>
            <from><![CDATA[/veelgestelde-vragen/(.*)/]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/faq/$1/]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </custom_url1>
    </rewrite>
    <rewrite>
        <custom_url2>
            <from><![CDATA[/account/bestelling/(.*)/]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/sales/order/view/order_id/$1/]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </custom_url2>
    </rewrite>
</global>
```

Somehow the custom_url1 rewrite on it self does work, but when i add the custom_url2 rewrite it breaks the first one, and custom_url2 doesn't work as well. custom_url2 on itself doesn't work either.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiple rewrites should be written inside same  tag like below.

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <custom_url1>
            <from><![CDATA[/velgestelde-vragen/(.*)/]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/faq/$1/]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </custom_url1>
        <custom_url2>
            <from><![CDATA[/account/bestelling/(.*)/]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/sales/order/view/order_id/$1/]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </custom_url2>
    </rewrite>
</global>
```

Hope this helps you out. :)